# Is there any way to default values using lightning:recordForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

We'd like to use [lightning:recordForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm) to create new objects that are related to a given object so we need to be able to default the id of the related object.  I don't see any way of doing this in the documentation.  Am I missing something?

Comment: If you want to create a record, and that you want to "default" values during the process, you should consider using [force:createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:createRecord/documentation) event.

Comment: We did consider that.  The problem is that when you save the object the UI navigates to the object's record page.  We need to stay on our component and be able to update related records after the new object is created.   See: [lightning-component-createrecord-without-navigating-away-from-current-page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/226354/lightning-component-createrecord-without-navigating-away-from-current-page)

Comment: Unfortunately, if its not documented, that would mean that there's no such capability of doing it that way.

Comment: @Homerlex, in one of your posts, it was mentioend that the lightning:recordEditForm would better fit your use case (based on what you have provided in your posts) any reason why you have not chosen to use it?

Comment: @glls - recordForm would be lot less work (if we could get it to take defaults)

Comment: recordForm is not documented and is fairly new (lots of issues) recordEditForm allows you more flexibility on what actions to trigger, the layout you want amongst other things.